# Work Manager not scheduling notification when app is closed

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am trying to build a doctor-patient app where the doctor will upload the medical prescription of the patient and the patient will be reminded when its prescription will be successfully uploaded using firebase notification.
What I want is that I want to automatically schedule medicine reminders as per prescription as soon as the prescription is uploaded I have saved the data from firebase messaging service in local SQLite and try to schedule notification based on timing containing medicines patient need to be taken.

I have tried to use WorkManager but it's not working when I tried to schedule the message

```
 WorkManager wmanager;

WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).cancelAllWorkByTag("AL");

 PeriodicWorkRequest saveRequest =
                    new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS).setInitialDelay(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .addTag("AL")
                            .build();
 wmanager=WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    wmanager.enqueue(saveRequest);
```

Code in Upload Worker class

```
  dmed=handler.getMedicine("AL");
         shownotification( dmed);
```

//handler.getMedicine get data from local sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cancelling the work and then schedule it again, use a [unique worker](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work):

```
PeriodicWorkRequest saveRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest
                            .Builder(UploadWorker.class, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS).setInitialDelay(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .addTag("AL")
                            .build();
WorkManager wmanager=WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
wmanager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("UniqueName", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, saveRequest);
```

However, keep in mind that WorkManager doesn't guarantee exact timing on the delay.